# Protect WordPress Rest API to access from my Android App Only

Tags: json, wordpress, api, rest

I have created rest apis on my wp server . I dont want to open the api for public access just want to access it from my own app. The question was asked previously but its has not any clear answer . I tried to use JWT but on my case its not valid because on JWT i need to login the user which is not possible in my case . I just want any protection to my rest api to get access from my android app without login.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Think of it this way... Suppose you're expecting a friend for dinner.  Someone knocks at your door.  "Who is it?", you say.  "I'm your friend", the voice answers.

Now, is it really your friend at the door?  After all, you had to ask *them* who they were.  Maybe it's someone pretending to be your friend.  You can check the basics... were they expected at this time?  Do they sound like your friend?  But, you really don't know whether or not it's your friend.  It could be someone emulating the protocol and sounding like your friend.  This scenario is really no different than someone spoofing your app to make API calls.  It can identify itself as your app, and since you have to rely on this information, you can't really prove that it is or isn't your app making the API call.

Maybe in a different scenario, you have a party.  To get in to the party, you have to know the password.  However, you want this to be a really big party so you put flyers up all around town, and you include the password on the flyers.  This is like what you're doing when you have a publicly accessible app with the API key built into it.  Everybody has the password, so you're only protecting your API from random requests unfamiliar with your app.

JWT really has absolutely nothing at all to do with user logins.  But, JWT doesn't help you here anyway.  Even if you signed some tokens, they still have to be embedded in your app.

What you *can* do is mutually authenticate both ends with a TLS connection.  Use certificate pinning.  But even all this isn't fool proof.  It is still possible for someone to pretend to be your app.

There's no magic that can be done here.  If you want people to access your API, you have to give people access to your API.